# CakePHP-like validation in FuelPHP

Tags: validation, cakephp, fuelphp

Hey guys, our company is looking to start using FuelPHP as it's main framework for development.

Personally I come from a CakePHP background, and really like the way that Cake handles a lot of things, such as validation - i.e. set the rules once in the model, and everything works together to honour the rules.

Moving into Fuel, however, it looks like they have a different approach to this, where the validation rules need to be set in the controller. The down side of this is lots of repeated code - i.e., even if you only have *add* and *edit* actions, that's still two places that you need to define your rules.

Because of this, I was hoping that someone might be able to help me out and let me know if it's possible for the model to handle the validation?

Thank you :)

Comment: You should mark the answer as accepted, this is 7 months old.

Answer (score 3):

As I've been too busy lately, regretably I haven't gotten round to documenting a lot. There are a couple of options:

1. Create a set_form_fields() to use with validation that you pass an instance of the Fieldset class and should setup all fields (including validation). An example can be [found here](https://github.com/jschreuder/FuelDocGenerator/blob/develop/fuel/app/classes/model/article.php#L11) (though based on an outdated version of Fuel). Once you've got such a method in your model you can use `Validation::factory()->add_model('Model_Example')`
   (Rules can also be created within the model, prefix them with `_validation_` and you can use them when adding the model like above)
2. Set the validation rules in the `$_properties` property of a Orm\Model class and add the model like with 1. (the Orm\Model has the set_form_fields() method build in)
3. Add the Orm\Observer_Validation to your Orm\Model `$_observers` property and validation will be done upon saving your model, throwing a `ValidationFailed` exception when failing. The errors can be fetched by the classname from the Validation class after this, for example: when a Model_Example instance failed saving because of validation you can fetch the full validation instance using `Validation::instance('Model_Example')` or fetch the errors using `Validation::instance('Model_Example')->show_errors()`